# Php cart: how to store product information in cart

Tags: php, cart

I want to make implement Cart funcionality in Laravel. I chose [this plugin](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart). But here and in many others cart packages I see that cart row stores not a product id but full information (product name, options, price). But what if the product title or product price was changed? Then the user still sees the old title (price) and it will cause some inconvienences to him. What I do not understand, why most cart packages store full information in cart row.

So what is the right way to store cart data: full info or by keys (product_id, option_id, ...)?

Comment: The cart usually I do it using session, also only I store products IDs and then request the products information using ajex - so this will help me to get the updated titles and prices

Comment: @Fahed Alkaabi I think so, but why a lot of packages are built in completely another way. Are they all mistaken?

Comment: They are not mistaken for sure, but for less cost they use the faster way - if you store is own with one owner so no body will update product except you so the faster way is better

Comment: Storing all the data in the cart is helpful when you change the price or options. Then you have record of what they paid / received.

Comment: @Sean I do not see this as helpful. If the store owner changes the price, a simple user should see this change in cart (I do not mean this when a user already ordered the product). For example [shopify](https://www.shopify.com/) update price (title, options) in cart if they were changed by admin

Answer (score 0):

There is a preferred way to store cart information, and its the latter that you mentioned.

The reason for this is to not only increase the security of your shopping cart, but to also ensure that, as you rightly pointed out, customers are getting the right price, even after a change.

Typically what you want to do is store the product ID, any customisation options as well as a cart ID. Depending on the amount of products and the traffic you're receiving it may be unnecessary to work out the basket price each time a new page is loaded, and so typically you only work out a new price when a new product is added, taken away or modified; in addition to when the customer gets to the checkout area.

This serves several purposes,

- the first is that is ensure that when the cart is directly changed by
  a customer action, you can show an updated price.
- The second is that you cut down the amount of calculations you have to do by a large amount by only changing the prices in the basket when something acts upon it.
- You can ensure that customers cannot cheat the system by modifying the price, then going on to pay a different amount because you stored the price in the session.

I can't give you a more concrete answer because you've been fairly light on the specifics, but I hope this indicates the direction you should be heading in.